# arrange with period object (ms function) doesn't work - R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a time recorded in following format mm:ss where the minutes values can actually be greater than 59. I have parsed it as `chr`. Now I need to sort my observations in a descending order so I firstly created a `time2` variable with `ms` function and used `arrange` on the new variable. However arranging doesn't work and the values in the second column are totally mixed up.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
test <- structure(list(time = c("00:58", "07:30", "08:07", "15:45", "19:30", 
                            "24:30", "30:05", "35:46", "42:23", "45:30", "48:08", "52:01", 
                            "63:45", "67:42", "80:12", "86:36", "87:51", "04:27", "09:34", 
                            "12:33", "18:03", "20:28", "21:39", "23:31", "24:02", "26:28", 
                            "31:13", "43:03", "44:00", "45:38")), .Names = "time", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                 -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
test %>% mutate(time2 = ms(time)) %>% arrange(time2) %>% View()
```

How can I arrange this times?

Comment: with base::sort() instead of arrange it works

Comment: but I need to arrange whole table

Comment: it's weird but if you take the View() out from the script everything yields errors, and if you remove time2 from arrange, at least it gives you the correct ms from time; i think it has to do with minutes being greater than 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to just put `time` in te same unit and then `arrange()`. Try this:

```
test %>% mutate(time_in_seconds = minute(ms(time) )*60 + second(ms(time))) %>%
  arrange(desc(time_in_seconds)) %>%
  View()

seconds_to_period(minute(ms(test$time))*60 + second(ms(test$time))) # to get right format (with hours)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation with arrange. dplyr does not support S4 objects: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/515